# How to convert new images to fashion-mnist data set images format?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, mnist

I have a neural network model which is trained on fashion-MNIST data set.
Now i'm predicting ,using the model ,some new random images (from google) and want to convert them to the same format as the images from the fashion-MNIST 
data set.
Can someone please provide me python code/functions that can help me do that ? 
Thank you.

I know that the format of the images from the data set is 28X28 pixels,grey-scale.
What i don't know, is how to convert new images to the same format exactly.
So that the model will predict those new images properly.

Comment: too wide. Please share your code what you are trying.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. First you will need to crop the random images from Google to 28x28 px, and then create an array of them. If you share link to some of these random images you refer to, next steps can be discussed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to do this; here's an example, although I'm sure it's far from the best.

```
num_imgs = len(os.listdir(my_path))
X = np.empty([int(num_imgs),28,28,1]) # in which to put the images
for i,image in enumerate(os.listdir(my_path)):
    the_img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(my_path,image),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    the_img = cv2.resize(the_img,(28,28))
    X[i] = the_img
```

Then X is like a stack of N pictures with dims 28x28 and one channel, i.e. (N,28,28,1).
Hope that helps!

Edit: Hey also, keep in mind that some packages like Keras have great tools to streamline this process (including labels, random transformations, etc). Highly recommend checking out [these tools.](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy or OpenCV to convert images to change into numpy array then resize and reshape it according to your model.